# Discord bot: Command Handler alias for command name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am working on a Discord bot, and trying to improve my already functioning command handler.
I have a folder, and every file is an extra command. I want to expand the system, so I have alias name for the same command, e.g. I want my clearchat command to function with /clearchat or with /cc, but I dont want to create just another file and copy the code. This is what I have:

```
// I left out the other imports etc.
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

// Reading commands-folder
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands/").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command); 
}

client.on("message", msg => {

    if (msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix) && !msg.author.bot && msg.guild) {
        const args = msg.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(" ");
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        
        if (client.commands.find(f => f.name === command)) {
            client.commands.get(command).execute(client, msg, args);    
        }
    }
});
```

and then a command file inside the commands-folder:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "clearchat",
    execute(client, msg, args) {
        if (msg.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
              msg.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 99}).then(messages => {
                  msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
              });
        }
    }
}
```

(I know it only deletes 100 messages max, I am fine with that)

I image something in changing a few lines in my client.on("message) function, and just having to write in the clearchat.js file a line like `name: ["clearchat", "cc", ...]` where I can go writing as much aliases as  I want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think we have to assume, that every alias/name is used only a single time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll have to create an array with the aliases in your command.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "clearchat",
    aliases: ["cc"],
    execute(client, msg, args) {
        
    }
}
```

Then, the same you did with commands, create a Collection for the aliases.

```js
client.aliases = new Discord.Collection()
```

And finally, bind the alias to the command:

```js
if (command.aliases) {
    command.aliases.forEach(alias => {
        client.aliases.set(alias, command)
    })
}
```

---

Now, when you want to execute a command, you'll have to check if it has an alias.

```js
const commandName = "testcommand" // This should be the user's input.
const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.aliases.get(commandName); // This will return the command and you can proceed by running the execute method.
```

---

```js
fs.readdir(`./commands/`, (error, files) => {
    if (error) {return console.log("Error while trying to get the commmands.");};
    files.forEach(file => {
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        const commandName = file.split(".")[0];

        client.commands.set(commandName, command);

        if (command.aliases) {
            command.aliases.forEach(alias => {
                client.aliases.set(alias, command);
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: You should paste it where you initialize the commands but at the end. So yes, in your for loop. I've updated my answer with an example.