# Discord.js Aliases

Tags: node.js, discord.js, aliases

i would like to add aliases in my code but i dont know how to embed it. You have an idea ?

```js
fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
      if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
      let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
      console.log(`Attempting to load command ${commandName}`);
      client.commands.set(commandName, props);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. I think you're going to need to be a bit more specific and give us some additional details on what you expect to achieve. 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot: Command Handler alias for command name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139763/discord-bot-command-handler-alias-for-command-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your command files to have aliases in them like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'command',
    description: 'description',
    aliases: ['cmd', 'another alias'],
    execute(message, args) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Then if you wanted to find a command by it's alias you can use:

```js
client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases.includes("an alias"));
```

You can find more about using aliases in this [guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#command-aliases)

Comment: and where do I put it? 

client.commands.find (cmd => cmd.aliases.includes ("an alias"));

Comment: That is optional, it allows you to find commands via their aliases as well as by name.